# Apscheduler. Как при перезагрузке сервера не дублировать задачи?

Tags: python, apscheduler

Подскажите, пожалуйста, при запуске скрипта генерируются задачи по крону, но при перезапуске скрипта, они дублируются повторно и так каждую перезагрузку.
Выполняются так же все, которые сгененировались. Как можно исправить это?

```
jobstores = {
    'default': RedisJobStore(host=os.getenv('REDIS_HOST'), port=os.getenv('REDIS_PORT'), db=0,
                             password=os.getenv('REDIS_PASSWORD'))
}

executors = {
    'default': AsyncIOExecutor()
}

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, timezone='Europe/Moscow')


scheduler.add_job(send_notify_tomorrow_sobes, trigger=CronTrigger.from_crontab('0 18 * * *'))
scheduler.add_job(send_sobes_link, trigger=CronTrigger.from_crontab('0 * * * *'))
scheduler.add_job(after_sobes, trigger=CronTrigger.from_crontab('0 * * * *'))
```